# Minecraft not opening in portable drive, only opening in Applications

Tags: applications, catalina, games

When I try to launch Minecraft on my portable drive, I get the error message *"Minecraft.app" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Bin.*:

[image]

but, when I move it to `/Applications` and double click, it starts. You can watch the full video here: https://youtu.be/Oo4R8UthaEM

This only happens when opening Minecraft. How can I stop this? Why is this happening?

I am using MacOS Catalina 10.15.1.

Comment: What file format is your portable drive? exFAT, HFS+, APFS?

Comment: My drive format is exFAT.

Comment: I can't say why it's not happening in /Applications, but that's a Gatekeeper message. Try right clicking the app and selecting "Open".

Answer (score -2):

I believe Minecraft was created so that it can only work when i's in applications folder because they don't want people to be able to play it on other peoples hard drives, they want them to pay money to buy it for themselves. This is just another trick they use to make themselves *more* money.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Be sure to address directly the question being asked. If you can review the [tour] closely, we are not a forum but place for specific answers to practical questions.